# Facebook dialog sharing is not parsing emoji correctly

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, share

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog

The sample fb dialog sharing can be tested here.
http://www.fbrell.com/saved/2779dc018c325d85d650a3b723239650

```
FB.ui({
 method: 'share',
 display: 'popup',
 quote:'I am title ⭐ 0x1F601 :) ',
 href: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/',
}, function(response){});
```

I want an emoji to be passed in the quote but on share, the decoded text has some garbage value in place of emoji.

[image]

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?